# Why aren't the functions working for displaying my images in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, image-gallery

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and I cant seem to get my code to work. I have this assignment that's long overdue and I cannot seem to get my goForward() ">>>" and goBackward() "<<<" functions to work properly. It's supposed to start at the index and each time you click the ">>>" button, it'll show the next image in the array. Same for the "<<<" button. I have 5 images in my array, and the ">>>" is showing 4 images then going back to the 1st image. The "<<<" is just broken. Sometimes it'll show the previous image and then skip to the 5th image. After that, it wont work. Something is broken and I can't figure it out. Please help!! Here is my code https://codepen.io/oshitaiya/pen/mddNWaq`enter code here` . Here is my assignment requirements https://docs.google.com/document/d/12IcETUGbgxC4jKBs0BK8HHLrjB_35mVlqK1kGTVIg-Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself. If it is too large make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. External sites wont always be there so information could someday be lost making the question useless for future users. Not to mention we shouldnt have to go offsite to see the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

By keeping what you have. Running all the logic BEFORE appending.

```js
var kawaii = ["https://media.giphy.com/media/3oKIPy2hjnheNraWwo/giphy.gif",
"https://media1.giphy.com/media/l3UcgEIw80eyb36kU/source.gif",
"https://media1.giphy.com/media/xTiN0mN3wxWO0MDuGk/source.gif",
"https://media2.giphy.com/media/3o6EhPDMjaDP5UC4ZW/source.gif",
"https://66.media.tumblr.com/3b9394556e6e0c6271594be2339c5d21/tumblr_nqkmdcPzbd1qak30bo1_500.gifv"]

var index = 0

function goForward(){
    index++
    if (index > kawaii.length - 1) {
         index = 0
    }
    document.getElementById("imgid").src = kawaii[index]
}

function goBackward(){
    index--
    if (index < 0) {
        index = kawaii.length - 1
    }
    document.getElementById("imgid").src = kawaii[index]
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much. I've been stuck on this for a few weeks. I really appreciate the help!!